# POV Ray Rendering fails

Tags: 3d, povray

I am trying to render this code using POVRay 3.7:

```
#include "colors.inc"
#include "glass.inc"
#include "golds.inc"
#include "metals.inc"
#include "stones.inc"
#include "woods.inc"
#include "shapes.inc"
#include "textures.inc"
#include "spectral.inc"
#include "rand.inc"
#include "math.inc"


#declare MaxTrace    = 60;
#declare Radio       = 1;
#declare Photons     = 10000000;
#declare Sunlight    = 0;
#declare SkyEmission = 5;

#declare RoomDesign  = 1;


camera {                                // sPlace the camera
  sky <0,0,1>                           // Zenith of camera attached  Ref Frame
  direction <-1,0,0>                    // First look at left of the screen plane
  right <4/3,0,0>                       // Right side expanded 
  location  <50,0,120>                  // Camera location
  look_at   <8,5,50>                    // Where camera is pointing
  angle 50                              // Angle of the view
}

global_settings { ambient_light White } //Ambient light to "brighten up" darker pictures

#declare Lamp = union {
  light_source {<0,0,6>, SpectralEmission(E_Blackbody(5500)) * 2000
  fade_power 2
  fade_distance 5
  photons {reflection on refraction on }
  }

  sphere { 0, 5
    pigment { SpectralEmission(E_Blackbody(5500)) }
    finish {emission 3 ambient 0 diffuse 0}
    no_shadow
    no_radiosity
  }

  translate <0, 150, 200>
}

object {Lamp}

background { color White}


/*plane {
  <0,-0,1>, -2                          //This represents the plane 0x+0y+z=0
  texture { Copper_Metal}               //The texture comes from the file "metals.inc"
   }*/

#declare alp =  32.0*pi/180;            // this is the shells own angular constant
#declare bet = -12.0*pi/180;            // "
#declare omg =  1.5*pi/180;             // rotation angle
#declare mu  =  29*pi/180;              // "
#declare phi =  17*pi/180;              // "
#declare A   =  20;                     // size
#declare D1  =  1;                      // direction of coiling
#declare D2  = -1;                      // ditto
#declare N   =  7;                      // Number of spines
#declare W1  =  5*pi/180;               // angle of spines
#declare W2  = 27*pi/180;               // "
#declare L   = 8*pi/180;                // "
#declare P   = 3*pi/180;                // "



#declare a = 40;                        // Apperture semi major axis
#declare b = 17;                        // Apperture semi minor axis 
#declare aperture_R = function(u,v) {
                                1 / sqrt(
                                            pow(cos(u)/a,2)
                                        +   pow(sin(u)/b,2)
                                        )
                                    }
#declare l = function(u) { 
                            (2*pi/N) * 
                                        (
                                              N*u/(2*pi) - 
                                        floor(N*u/(2*pi))
                                        ) 
                        }

object {

    parametric {
        function { D1 * (
                                A*sin(bet)*cos(v) 
                            +           cos(u)*cos(v)*aperture_R(u,v) 
                            -           sin(u)*sin(v)*aperture_R(u,v) 
                        ) * exp(v/tan(alp)) 
                }
        function { (
                            -1* A*sin(bet)*sin(v) 
                            -           cos(u)*sin(v)*aperture_R(u,v) 
                            -           sin(u)*cos(v)*aperture_R(u,v) 
                    )*exp(v/tan(alp))
                }
        function { (
                            -1* A*cos(bet) 
                            +           sin(u)*aperture_R(u,v) 
                    )*exp(v/tan(alp))
                }
        <0,0>,<pi,pi>
        accuracy 0.01
        precompute 10 x,y,z
    }
    texture {NBwinebottle}
    rotate <0,20,47>
    scale <4,4,4>
}
```

I took the code from [here](http://www.mat.uc.pt/%7Epicado/conchas/eng/article.pdf).

However, the only render is the white screen. I have tried shuffling `u` and `v` parameters. I have tried changing the camera position and direction. However, I see nothing.

Where did I go wrong? I am pretty sure I did the equations correct, but please help me. I really need help. Thank you.